# Launching a program straight from OS

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, distro

I am developing a program similar to xbmc but only for movies. I was wondering if there is any very simple operating system that will basically just boot and run the program I am developing? Similar to what openelec does for XBMC. I can run it on windows but I want to be able to put it on a machine like raspberry pi without having to have a whole windows or linux OS.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: This is something you needed to think about before you started developing your program.

Comment: The program was for an assignment a while back so I needed to do it a different way to begin with. I just want to continue it on my own. That is why I am here.

Comment: Just be prepared to redo most of your existing work, then.

Comment: Linux comes in all shapes and sizes. Just because something like mint looks like way too much, doesn't mean that there isn't an embedded distro perfect for this. Remember, Linux is an incredibly efficient and dynamic OS that can fit itself to anything from something like the Raspberry Pi to something like an IBM supercomputer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the rather slim linux distributions specialized in embedded systems, like firewalling distros and so on.

Then, if it is a graphical application you have to make sure you boot into runlevel 5 (graphics) and configure your application as login shell for the default user.

---

You might also be interested in two services the openSUSE project offers: the Open Build Service (OBS) and SUSE Studio:

- OBS allows you to automatically get packages of your application built and packaged, ready for use in a number of wide spread distributions.
- Studio allows you to go a step further and create a custom distribution for your own purpose: you can call it 'your' operating system, completely preconfigured for your purpose, with all requried software and your own application installed. You just have to download a CD image afterwards!

Comment: Thank you for the information. This was a very informative post! I will look into OBS and SUSE.